# nodeJS draw image into a canvas (not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, canvas, express

I try to make a game with nodeJS in Back-end and AngularJS in Front-End but i have some problems.
I use express to configure routes in NodeJS and ngRoute in AngularJS. Each page have a view and a controller.
I have a page who just has a "canvas" into its view and a controller to manage the canvas (this code is an example, it's not my final code) :

gameView.html :

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

gameCtrl.js :

```
app.controller('gameCtrl', function($scope) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }
    img.src = 'image.png';
});
```

The problem is that in Google Chrome and only with NodeJS (i already tried with Apache), after X refresh, the drawImage doesn't work.

I already have disabled the GPU acceleration of Chrome or used the "document.createElement("img")".
But nothing work.

In NodeJS, i have defined a public folder like that :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And the image, html and js files are in the public folder.
So, i don't know why it doesn't work.

**If you have any idea thanks to give me a feedback.**

(I am sorry for my english, i am french)

**EDIT :**
I have created a workspace at Cloud9 website.

To test : https://testcanvas-c9-lludol.c9.io/

To see the code : https://ide.c9.io/lludol/testcanvas

Like you can see, it works !
I even have tried to reproduce the route system in this workspace.

So, do you think it's my server who have a problem ?

Or do you think there is a problem my nodeJS configuration ?

**I found a solution :**
Instead of creating an image with "new Image()", i can store the base64 encoded of the image and display it directly with "drawImage".

Comment: Your canvas id is `gameCanvas` but you use `toto` in `getElementById`...

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. In my real code there is no problem like that in my real code.

Comment: *after X refresh* sounds like a classic race condition. Are you sure your code execution is deferred until the DOM is ready?

Comment: I added $(funcition(){}) to start the code when the DOM is ready and it changes nothing. I will paste the code.